# Delete a class object in C++

Tags: c++

I'm doing a simple Zombie island game in the console and I'm trying to make the zombies die when the human lands on them.

To create the zombies I used my Zombie class like this:

```
Zombies *zombie = new Zombies[4];
```

To check if the human and the zombie are on the same place I used a simple for loop:

```
int zombieCount = 4;
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    if (player.getPosX() == zombie[i].getPosX() && player.getPosY() == zombie[i].getPosY())
    {
        zombieCount--;

    }
}
```

Besides decreasing the zombieCount, the zombie I hit should disappear from the game. How do I do that?

Comment: This problem is a lot easier if you use standard containers. For example, you can use `std::vector<Zombie>`, which allows you to remove zombies at will and avoids using pointers and manual memory management at all.

Comment: I would go with std::vector<Zombie>

Comment: Can't you set the position of zombie i outside the grid/to null value, so it would never be picked again?

Comment: @FLab Assuming I understand you correctly, that would result in a memory leak.

Comment: It's not a leak if delete [] zombie is executed at the end. But it's a bad idea to force yourself to keep track of the new/delete pairing.

Answer (score 2):

In C++11, you can use `std::remove(first, last, value)` to remove certain elements in an array. The function returns the new array ending, e.g. use:

```
auto end = std::remove(std::begin(zombie), std::end(zombie), zombie[i]);
```

I'd suggest to use `std::vector` which is a dynamic array which suits more your needs.

References: [std::remove](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) and [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

**Suggested std::vector example:**

```
std::vector<Zombies> zombies;
// init with zombies.push_back(someZombie);

for (vector<Zombies>::iterator it = zombies.begin(); it != zombies.end(); /*no ++it*/) {
  if (player.getPosX() == it->getPosX() && player.getPosY() == it->getPosY())
      it = zombies.erase(it);
  else 
      ++it;
}

int zombieCount = zombies.size();
```

Comment: `std::remove` returns the new theoretical iterator to end, you must call `erase` on the vector afterwards to make it discard the elements past that iterator! Therefore, `zombie.erase(end, zombie.end());`

Comment: But it's not a vector, it's new Zombie[4], so this is no different from just swapping the zombie with the last and doing --zombieCount, and the lack of a delete [] zombie at the end remains an issue.

Comment: If you erase all the elements directly in the loop, you do a lot of unnecessary copies - prefer two iterators and copy the second one to the first one, if the zombie should stay. Then you can erase only the end of the vector. Actually, that is what you get with `erase(std:.remove[_if](...), end()`, too.

Comment: Valid point, for the given use case I assume that it is not very likely, that 100s of zombies are at the same position as the player? @Oana

Comment: No, I'll have maximum 10 zombies at the same time on the map.

Comment: Hm, and probably, there won't ever be two zombies at the same location either? Then I'd simply break the loop after a match: `for(auto i = v.begin(); i != v.end(); ++i) { if([...]) { v.erase(i); break; } }`

Comment: It is possible for 2 zombies to be in the same spot. Small chances, but still possible, as they spawn in a random place on the map and move by 1 space in a random direction every time the player moves.

Answer (score 1):

You can use std::erase-remove_if with lambda as in following one-liner:

```
zombies.erase(std::remove_if(zombies.begin(), zombies.end(),
                  [& player](const Zombie& z){return player.getPosX() == z.getPosX() && player.getPosY() == z.getPosY();}),
              zombies.end());
```

Supposed you have a `vector<Zombie> zombies` or `list<Zombie>` or another container that can be reordered.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `vector` container:

```
Zombies zombieModel;

std::vector<Zombies> zombieVec(10, zombieModel);

int zombieCount = zombieVec.size();
for (int i = 0; i < zombieVec.size(); i++)
{
    if (player.getPosX() == zombieVec[i].getPosX() && player.getPosY() == zombieVec[i].getPosY())
    {
        zombieCount--;
        zombieVec.erase(zombieVec.begin()+i);
        i--;
    }
}
```

Comment: don't use zombieCount, use zombieVec.size()

Comment: Or use `erase` with `remove_if` and a lambda.

Comment: You can simply use the `std::vector<Zombie>::vector(size_t, Zombie);` to initialize.

Comment: Is there any way to work with the zombies in a single line of code or so? Because if I need like 10 of them it'd be quite a lot of code as I also have to spawn and move them.

Comment: @OanaFurtună I Edited to do it in one line. Thanks to  FrançoisAndrieux

Comment: To create 10 zombies shouldn't it be
`std::vector<Zombies> zombieVec(10, zombieModel);`  ?

Comment: @OanaFurtună Yes, it is OK now!

Comment: I personally think iterators read nicer: `for(auto i = vec.begin(); i != vec.end();)`, then you have `i->getPosXY()` and `vec.erase(i)` - only disadvantage: you as you erase, you need to move the ++i into the loop: `if([...]) i = vec.erase(i); else ++i;`

Comment: Okai, I think I got it now. Thank you!

Comment: You really should take another look at NathanOliver's comment. Here's some more detail https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom

Answer (score 0):

NathanOliver recommended in a comment to use `std::remove_if` - in my eyes best of the so far proposed solutions, unfortunately it is just a comment, so I illustrate here how it could look like (a little shortened by just comparing the X-coordinate...):

```cpp
Person p;
std::vector<Zombie> zombies(4);
auto end = std::remove_if
    (
        zombies.begin(), zombies.end(),
        [&p](Zombie const& zombie) { return (zombie.getPosX() == p.getPosX()) && (zombie.getPosY() == p.getPosY()); }
    );
zombies.erase(end, zombies.end());
```